# Choosing the number of hidden layers and nodes in a Deep Belief Network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, references, deep-belief-networks

What are the recent advances and current best practices in choosing the number and size of stacked Restricted Boltzmann Machines in Deep Belief Networks ?